# Hashicorp Vault: Is it possible to make edits to pre-existing server configuration file?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, hashicorp-vault

I have a Kubernetes cluster which utilizes Vault secrets. I am attempting to modify the `conf.hcl` that was used to establish Vault.  I went into the pod which contains Vault, and appended:

```
max_lease_ttl = "999h" 
default_lease_ttl = "999h"
```

I did attempt to apply the changes using the only server option available according to the documentation, but failed due to it already being established:

```
vault server -config conf.hcl
Error initializing listener of type tcp: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:8200: bind: address already in use
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't reinitialize in the pod since it's the port is already bound on the containers (Vault is already running there).

You need to restart the pod/deployment with a new config. Not sure how your Vault deployment is configured but the config could be in the container itself, or in some mounted volume or perhaps a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/).